# RFID Reader UART

Tags: arduino, rfid, uart, serial

Was wondering if someone could give me a hand with a project that I am undertaking. I have searched forums high and low and am yet to find the information to solve my problems.

Basically I have an RFID Reader (an ID20) and I have an Arduino Duemilanove.

I want to read the RFID data in, but I am not able to use Digital Pin 0 because I am using 1 and 0 to connect to a PC for Serial Communication. My assumed solution for this was to use a UART of some type to store the information until it is ready to be read by the Arduino (perhaps through SoftwareSerial). I cannot use SoftwareSerial because I need other actions to be performed between receiving RFID data, and SoftwareSerial pauses the Arduino until it receives data from the RFID.

Not sure if I can use an FTDI USB UART ... can I?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a software serial driver which runs under interrupt rather than polling the pin.

Check [this](http://arduiniana.org/libraries/NewSoftSerial/) out.